# How can I handle when remote bluetooth device suddenly is disconnected?

Tags: android, bluetooth

First, I don't speak English well. Please consider this.

I'm implementing bluetooth application.

When my android phone(bluetooth application) moves far behind remote device and finally remote device is disconnected, I want toast message("disconnected") to be appeared in my phone.

Please explain in simple word how I implement this task.

Comment: I implement connection task with AsyncTask.

Comment: Bluetooth Low Energy? You should have a callback `onConnectionStateChange` method, that will receive a disconnect "message". When this is received you can display the toast.